# Pandas add a new column with a string where the cell match a particular condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm trying to apply Pandas style to my dataset and add a column with a string with the matching result.

This is what I want to achieve:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Vdo.jpg)

[image]

Below is my code, an expert from stackflow assisted me to apply the df.style so I believe for the df.style is correct based on my test. However, how can I run iterrows() and check the cell for each column and return/store a string to the new column 'check'? Thank you so much. I'm trying to debug but not able to display what I want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))

df['check'] = None

def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    m = pd.concat([(x['A'] > 6), (x['B'] > 2), (x['C'] < 3)], axis=1)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    return df1.mask(m, c1)

def check(v):

    for index, row in v[[A]].iterrows():
        if row[A] > 6: 
            A_check = f'row:{index},' + '{0:.1f}'.format(row[A]) + ">6"
            return A_check

    for index, row in v[[B]].iterrows():
        if row[B] > 2:
            B_check = f'row:{index}' + '{0:.1f}'.format(row[B]) + ">2"
            return B_check

    for index, row in v[[C]].iterrows():
        if row[C] < 3:
            C_check = f'row:{index}' + '{0:.1f}'.format(row[C]) + "<3"
            return C_check


df['check'] = df.apply(lambda v: check(v), axis=1)

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

This is the error message I got:

> **NameError**: name 'A' is not defined

Comment: `['A']` instead of `[A]` etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried ['A'] but failed. It shows an error code " 'int' object has no attribute 'iterrows' "

Comment: Yes, indeed. `v` is a Series. If you evaluate it at `'A'` (`A` makes no sense), then the result is an integer, which can't be `iterrow`-ed.  So this `for index, row in v[[A]].iterrows():` doesn't make sense. The question now is: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Timus Actually I simplified my real code into a more readable example. My attempt was to highlight a particular cell where the value matches the criteria and output a note in the added column as a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the following produces what you are trying to achieve with the `check` function:

```
def check(v):
    row_str = 'row:{}, '.format(v.name)
    checks = []
    if v['A'] > 6: 
        checks.append(row_str + '{:.1f}'.format(v['A']) + ">6")
    if v['B'] > 2:
        checks.append(row_str + '{:.1f}'.format(v['B']) + ">2")
    if v['C'] < 3:
        checks.append(row_str + '{:.1f}'.format(v['C']) + "<3")    
    return '\n'.join(checks)

df['check'] = df.apply(check, axis=1)
```

Result (`print(df)`):

```
    A  B  C                                      check
0  10  3  1  row:0, 10.0>6\nrow:0, 3.0>2\nrow:0, 1.0<3
1   3  7  2                 row:1, 7.0>2\nrow:1, 2.0<3
2   2  4  4                               row:2, 4.0>2
```

(Replace `\n` with `' '` if you don't want the line breaks in the result.)

The `axis=1` option in `apply` gives the function `check` one row of `df` as a Series with the column names of `df` as index (-> `v`). With `v.name` you'll get the corresponding row index. Therefore I don't see the need to use `.iter...`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Thank you @Timus Your code looks very simplified without using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in program which we will fix one by one

1. Import pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
```

2. In function check(v): var A, B, C are not defined, replace them with 'A', 'B', 'C'. Then v[['A']] will become a series, and to iterate in series we use `iteritems()` and not iterrows, and also index will be column name in  series. Replacing will give

```py
def check(v):
    truth = []
    for index, row in v[['A']].iteritems():
        if row > 6: 
            A_check = f'row:{index},' + '{0:.1f}'.format(row) + ">6"
            truth.append(A_check)

    for index, row in v[['B']].iteritems():
        if row > 2:
            B_check = f'row:{index}' + '{0:.1f}'.format(row) + ">2"
            truth.append(B_check)

    for index, row in v[['C']].iteritems():
        if row < 3:
            C_check = f'row:{index}' + '{0:.1f}'.format(row) + "<3"
            truth.append(C_check)
    return '\n'.join(truth)
```

This should give expected output, although you need to also add additional logic so that check column doesnt get yellow color. This answer has minimal changes, but I recommend trying axis=1 to apply style columnwise as it seems more convenient. Also you can refer to [style guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/style.html)
[image]

Comment: Thank you @root163 Your code also works for me and point out my incorrect coding. I really appreciate your help but have to give a best and simplified solution to another answer.